# How to do this Scala exercise in functional way?

Tags: scala, user-interface, functional-programming, monads, state-pattern

Suppose I am writing a simple GUI exercise in Scala: There is a shape (e.g. circle or square) in a window and a user may drag it with the mouse.

I can write it in Java with the *State pattern* (see the details below):

...

The application has 2 states: IDLE when nothing happens and DRAGGING when the user is dragging the shape. It starts with IDLE.

Both states handles 3 mouse events:

- mouse pressed
- mouse released
- mouse moved

IDLE handles the mouse events as follows:

- on *mouse pressed* if the mouse position is inside the shape move to the DRAGGING state
- on *mouse released* and *mouse moved* do nothing

DRAGGING handles them as follows:

- on *mouse released* move to the IDLE state
- on *mouse released* do nothing
- on *mouse moved* move the shape

...

Now I wonder how to implement it in Scala in a *functional* way.
This computation looks inherently stateful. Would you suggest using the *State monad* ?

Comment: There's nothing "non-functional" about a state machine. In fact, the formal definition of an FSM [is mostly a function, with a bunch of other stuff thrown in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine#Mathematical_model).

Answer (score 3):

This could be handled even with simple tail recursion, but the problem here is "events". That usually means inversion of control. If you control the listen loop, then you can use recursion or state monad. If you do not, then your best is [Functional Reactive Programming (FRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_reactive_programming).

There are at least two FRP frameworks in Scala. One is EPFL's, which I don't know how close to production level is nor the exact name (though I think it's Reactive), and the other is called [Reactive](https://github.com/nafg/reactive), and it is fairly mature. Also, its author look at Scala questions on Stack Overflow, so you might get help here.

Comment: Suppose I do control the event loop. Could you show how to use recursion or state monad here ?